# How to get feature on vector layer in Openlayers 3?

Tags: geojson, vector, openlayers-2, events

I'm try to get feature of a vector layer, but I'll have 3 or more Vector layer. When I click the map, I didn't get the feature. My vector layer definition;

```
var vectorAltAlan = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
            projection: 'EPSG:2322',
            url: 'data/geojson/guneykaya_alt_alan.geojson'
        }),
        style: function (feature, resolution) {
            ...
    });
```

So how can I detect the layer and getting featue by click ?

Comment: Hi, 

This question was answered before in Stackoverflow; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297721/how-to-get-a-layer-from-a-feature-in-openlayers-3